# Issues adding libraries to xCode Project manually

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been trying to add SwiftyJSON and SWXMLHash to my Swift project, however when I add them the files have many (40+) compile errors?

I have read the instructions on there git projects carefully and both projects say I can just drag the .swift file to my project, and this is what I have been doing.

I can't use CocoaPods or Cartage as I am targeting iOS 7

Comment: Mismatch of Swift versions, maybe?  What are the errors?

Comment: Please elaborate you errors. Please also let us know your current running Xcode version.

Comment: Anyone ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue and don't want to use CocoaPods b/c of targeting iOS7.  My error is just that is says no such module exists when I add  the import SwiftyJSON line to one of my .swift files.  It's odd b/c I don't get the same error when I add import SwiftyJSON to viewcontroller.swift -- what's up with that?